# How to recreate object from class in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, class, oop

I have a simple class that loads json and converts it into dict.

```
class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, config_path):
        with open(config_path) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            super().__init__(**data)
```

I create an instance of a class by passing file location:

`config = Config(os.environ['CONFIG_PATH'])`

How can I recreate the object with the same parameter, but without passing this parameter? E.g. read file from the same path again.

I know, that I can simply pass the parameter again, create a new object and assign it to the same variable. I'm wondering if there is a common pattern for that.

In the end, I want to be able to do something like:

```
if something:
   config = config.reload()
# OR even
   config.reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to assign the path as an instance variable (so it remains available) e.g. `self._path = config_path`, then you can just add a method updating the internal state based on re-reading the file e.g.

```
def reload(self):
    with open(self._path) as f:
        self.update(json.load(f))
```